# Remove HTML TAG Inputs from input Form

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, input, keypress

Ok basically when I type , it won't allow it.
I want to add more like < > / \ etc how do I do it?

```
$("#in1").keypress(function (evt) {
    if (String.fromCharCode(evt.which) == ",")
        return false;
});


<input type="text" id="in1">
```

Can see the demo here. http://jsfiddle.net/QshDd/38/

Comment: what exactly u want to ask? please clear your question

Comment: Basically it's a signup form, it need to remove html tags etc on submit but this is easier then done.

Answer (score 4):

If you have a list of disallowed characters, you can forbid them in this fashion:

```
$("#in1").keypress(function (evt) {
    return [',', '<', '>', ].indexOf(String.fromCharCode(evt.which)) === -1;
});
```

Answer (score 2):

its working , you Required to give more conditions:

```
$("#in1").keypress(function (evt) {
if (String.fromCharCode(evt.which) == ",")
    return false;
if (String.fromCharCode(evt.which) == "<")
    return false;
if (String.fromCharCode(evt.which) == ">")
    return false;
if (String.fromCharCode(evt.which) == "\\")
    return false;
});
```

Another Solution , either use **regEx** or use XMLParser or JSON parser methods.

Comment: It does work, just too long, I never voted though. I voted now anyways, thanks!

Comment: no worry friend, Use REgEx, best way to do it, short and simple

Answer (score 1):

if you want something like this
`<input type="text">`   **===>** `input typetext`

```
  $("#in1").keypress(function (evt) {
    if (isValid(String.fromCharCode(evt.which)))
        return false;
    });

    function isValid(str){
      return /[~`!#$%\^&*+=\-\[\]\\';,/{}|\\":<>\?]/g.test(str);
    }
```

http://jsfiddle.net/QshDd/61/

Answer (score 0):

Try this, if you need only alphabets

```
$("#in1").keypress(function (evt) {
    var expr = /^([a-zA-Z\s]+)$/i;
    if (!String.fromCharCode(evt.which).match(expr))
        return false;
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var chars = new Array("<", ">" ,"/" ,"\\");
$("#in1").keypress(function (evt) {
    if(!(chars.indexOf(String.fromCharCode(evt.which)) > -1))
        return false;
});
```